# How can I get Rust code coverage to ignore unreachable lines?

Tags: rust, code-coverage

Using the following as an example:

```rust
fn get_num(input: i32) -> i32 {
    input*2
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_it() {
        for i in 1i32..72 {
            match get_num(i) {
                x if x%2 == 0 => { println!("even"); }
                _ => {println!("odd");}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and implementing the code coverage like so:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-C instrument-coverage" cargo test;
llvm-profdata merge -sparse default_*.profraw -o default.profdata;
executable=$(RUSTFLAGS="-C instrument-coverage" cargo test --no-run --message-format=json | \
  jq -r "select(.profile.test == true) | .filenames[]" | \
  \grep -v dSY);
llvm-cov show --instr-profile=default.profdata --object "$executable";
```

I would like the `println!("odd");` not to be marked as "not covered".

In javascript, I would use `istanbul-ignore-next` to ignore a line (mark them as "exercised"). In C#, one can use `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage`. Using, `lcov` (for C or C++), you can use `LCOV_EXCL_LINE`. In python, use `# pragma: no cover`. In ruby, use `# :nocov:`. Is there a way to do this in Rust?

Comment: In Rust, especially in production code, you should prefer not making it possible to encode states impossible to reach over having to handle impossible states with `unreachable!()` code or alike.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write unreachable code. If your test panics, it failed. If it doesn't panic, it succeeded. You don't need to examine output from the test to see if it succeeded or not.

As such, don't use `match`; use `assert_eq!`.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_it() {
        for i in 1i32..72 {
            assert_eq!(get_num(i) % 2, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

If the assertion fails, you'll get information in the test results about *why* it failed.

Comment: This is a minimal example. I'm actually wanting to ignore lines in "production" code.

Comment: Same answer for production code: if it's really unreachable, get rid of it. If not, then add a test that *can* reach it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea universally. For the sake of maintainability and defensive coding, putting messages like "This line shouldn't be reached, something is broken" is good documentation for the next maintainer as well as an early signal that something is going wrong. If code is written once by one developer and not modified ever again, I would agree: get rid of unreachable code.

Comment: So write a test that can do the broken thing to prove that your code handles it, no matter how weakly.

Comment: Such a line *can* be reached: you just aren't trying hard enough.

Comment: Rust has an `unreachable!` macro that serves as documentation and also a clear indication that an assumption has fallen over if it ever gets run. In the case of tests like this though, I would agree with @chepner's answer.

Comment: @chepner *if it's really unreachable, get rid of it. If not, then add a test that can reach it* - this is impossible for non-exhaustive enums. They require a catch-all pattern in `match`, but a test for that case *cannot be written*. Even if the catch-all were to end in `unreachable!()` (which is not a great approach in general), a test *could not* even be written to check the panic.

Answer (score 1):

`#[no_coverage]` can be applied to functions, but is not yet stable: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/84605. From that same ticket:

> Ignoring a statement or block is not currently supported.

Answer (score -1):

That's not *generally* possible because it would require for the compiler to do some super smart reasoning. In your particular case it's "obvious" that the match arm for odd numbers can't ever be reached, but what you're asking of the compiler (and the coverage tool) is to be a general *theorem prover*.

Basically the tool would need to come with some logic that can prove statements about the code. This is actually an unsolvable problem (undecidable, to be precise). You can make tools that can make pretty good attempts (the aforementioned theorem provers) but the complexity of such a tool would far eclipse what you'd want in a simple code coverage tool.

Comment: "you're asking ... the compiler ... to be a general theorem prover." Not at all. I would just like to be able to, for instance, `/* istanbul-ignore-next */`

Comment: Apologies, that wasn't quite clear from your question; it did sound indeed like you expected the compiler to realize that 2 * some_int is always going to be even...